# change progress unit of progressdialog (byte to megabyte)

Tags: java, android, progressdialog

I have a progress dialog which show the downloading of my files using byte as progress unit
I want to convert the progress unit into megabytes

```
public void initializeDialog()
    {
        this.pDialog = new ProgressDialog(act);
        this.pDialog.setMessage("Download");
        this.pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        this.pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        this.pDialog.setCancelable(true);
    }

    public AsynchTest() {
        initializeDialog();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

pDialog.setProgressNumberFormat("%1d MB / %2d MB");
        pDialog.show();
        pDialog.setProgress(0);

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        downloadContent();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {


        pDialog.incrementProgressBy((int) byteToMB(progress[0]));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        pDialog.dismiss();

    }
```

I use this function in order to convert bytes to mb

```
public long byteToMB(long byteTransform)
    {
        long mb=1024L*1024L;
        return byteTransform/mb;

    }
```

The code snippet i use to update my progress dialog

```
byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {  
                asynch.publishProgress(count);
                output.write(data, 0, count);


            }
```

I set the max of my progress dialog like this

```
sizePDialog+=ConnectionManager.getLength(url);
pDialog.setMax((int) byteToMB(sizePDialog));
```

but i go this error when i do this

```
04-07 20:09:55.119: E/AndroidRuntime(20166): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "%1d"
```

Thank you very much

Comment: what is byteTransform?

Comment: @pietmau Thank you for your reply . byteTransform is the progressunit i use to fill progress dialog. I updated my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should not call `setProgressNumberFormat` in `onProgressUpdate` like the doc says 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html#setProgressNumberFormat(java.lang.String)

> Change the format of the small text showing current and maximum units
>   of progress. The default is "%1d/%2d". Should not be called during the
>   number is progressing.

In fact `setProgressNumberFormat` only change the way the the progress and the max progress will be displayed you cannot change, like you tried, the value just before it is formatted.
What I would recommend you is to do the conversion byte to MB when you transmit the values to the Progress Dialog, and then the values will be formatted as MB.

Do to so you should replace the`pDialog.incrementProgressBy(progress[0]);` by `pDialog.incrementProgressBy(byteToMB(progress[0]));` and call

```
pDialog.setProgressNumberFormat("%1d MB / %2d MB");
```

in `onPreExecute`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and advices . I tried your solutions but now my progressdialog doesn t fill. It correctly displayed the format progress/23 mb instead progress/24117248 but the progress remains 0 . I updated my code with this case .

Comment: Oh i understand why my progressdialog doesn ' t fill . It s because (int) byteToMB(progress[0]) return 0 each time . I need to round the megabytes but i don t think we can because incrementProgressBy allow only int not double

Comment: Maybe you should use the `setProgress` instead of `incrementProgressBy` to do so, keep the number of MegaBytes read in a variable, and update direcly the progress with this variable

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time to help me  . It works perfectly now with setprogress instead incrementProgress( i don't understand however the diff between  the 2 method even if i read the doc)